# VLC application does not play after I manage to skip to the desired file location

Tags: windows-7, audio, vlc-media-player

I am trying to skip to random places in a 1MB (10 minute) [3GPP](http://www.3gpp.org/) phone call recording sound file on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. In order to do this, I associate the `.3gp` file extension with `VLC` and click on the file to open it.

However, when I open the file, the software does not seem to work as expected. As soon as I open the file the sound file plays. I click on the pause button which then turns into a play button. Then I try double-clicking on the blue progress bar to skip to the desired location, but I cannot do this immediately (immediately it does not work). After waiting some time, if I click anywhere on the progress bar, the control on the progress bar skips to some location slightly ahead of where I click (**why is this?**).

But **the worst part**, is that once I skip by clicking on the progress bar to set the location of the control which determines at what length of time we skip to in the file, **and pres the play button, nothing happens!!!**.

- Can someone explain to me why this is not working?
- Is there some better software out there that allows me to skip and play at a specified location with a 3GPP file? I thought VLC was supposed to be a relatively good app!!!

I was wondering, perhaps I need to convert the file to some other format so that the behavior I am trying to achieve can be handled more easily by VLC and other apps. Is this what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the file to an mp3 and work with that. To do this, fire up VLC and go to `Media | Convert / Save...`, click on `Add...` and browse to the desired 3GPP and open it. Then click on the `Convert / Save` button in the lower right part of the window. Select `Audio - MP3` from the combo box and click on the `Browse` button to choose the destination file, then click on `Start`.

Interesting to note that 1MB 3GPP file (with the settings I've used) produces a 10MB MP3 file increasing the size of the file tenfold.